# Level replacement in R shiny creates two level lists, one with NULL

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working for the first time on a shiny app.

Based on an uploaded xlsx, the shiny app creates an reactive output called `garnetRF()`. Based on the number of differently named samples in the uploaded xlsx, the app creates dynamic tabs in `output$tabp`. In the tabs, the user can pick a color to be displayed for each sample. So far, so good.

Now, in the `ouput$setting` I want to plot the results with the colors the user picked. Thus, my idea was to rename the sample levels by the picked color names (`cls.0`). However, when performing the code as following, two level lists are produced and I don't understand why:

```
output$tabp <- renderUI({
    req(garnetRF())
    l = length(unique((garnetRF()[,"sample"])))
    
    myTabs <- lapply(1:l, function(i) {
      tabPanel(title = as.list(factor(unique(garnetRF()[,"sample"])))[[i]],
               colourInput(paste0("col_", i), NULL, paste0("FF000", i), showColour = "background")
      )
    })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  })
  
  output$setting <- renderPlot({
    l2 = length(unique((garnetRF()[,"sample"])))
    cls.0 = factor((garnetRF()[,"sample"]))
    levels(cls.0) = factor((sapply(1:l2, function(j){input[[paste0("col_", j)]]})))
    print(levels(cls.0))
```

```
[1] "NULL"
[1] "#FF0001" "#FF0002" "#FF0003"
```

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this....

Comment: Try `req()` in output$setting as `output$setting <- renderPlot({ req(garnetRF())
    l2 = length(unique((...`

Comment: Nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I think the right approach is

```
levels(cls.0) = sapply(1:l2, function(j){input[[paste0("col_", j)]]})
```

since levels of a factor is just a vector of strings.

Comment: When using this, I get this error: Error in rep.int: invalid 'times' value

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve this invalid 'times' value error and where it is coming from?

Comment: check out l2, maybe it is 0?

Comment: l2 is 3 in this case